# Pass array parameter from C# to Oracle for use in select where in statement

Tags: c#, oracle, plsql

try to parse array parameter to oracle for use it in select where in statement:

**c#**:

```
string[] arr = new string { "aaa", "bbb" };
```

**Oracle**:

```
type str_table is table of varchar2(20);
procedure sp_test ( p_arr in str_table )
is
begin
select *
  from table 
 where field in (select column_value
                   from table(p_arr))
end;
```

Its not work. Error is cant access table not initialized...

Comment: Please post the exact error message and the code you are using to call the procedure. Also, is the Oracle code being create in the SQL scope or in a package?

Comment: This is how to do it in Java: [How to pass List from java to Oracle Procedure](http://stackoverflow.com/a/37161584/1509264)

Comment: Possible duplicate: [Calling an Oracle procedure with a PL/SQL collection type parameter via .NET](http://stackoverflow.com/a/29608014/1509264)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9700173/odp-net-how-to-pass-array-of-strings-to-an-oracle-stored-procedure

Comment: Also - if you are using an Oracle collection you do not need to do `WHERE column_name IN ( SELECT COLUMN_VALUE FROM TABLE( array ) )` instead you can simply do `WHERE column_name MEMBER OF array`.

Comment: Show us your c# code

Comment: Before c# code the package is not compiled :)
when changed to member of p_arr get error PLS-00382 expression is of wrong type, but type is same, varchar2.

Comment: Show us than the pl/sql code. Where are the 'CREATE' , where is the select into or this select is open for cursor